# Changing value from 0 to 1 in unityscript and unity3D

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can i randomize this set of array without getting the same value? I don't know if I'm doing it right. How can it recognize the value when it was change?

```
function Start () 
    {
    if(MasterVar.quiz<10)
    {
        var englishLecture = [
        ["Word that tells us about an action","Verb","Noun","Pronoun","a","0"],
        ["Name of person, place or things","Verb","Noun","Cute","b","0"],
        ["Select the noun","Swim","Shout","Joe","c","0"],
        ["There __ a cat","is","was","can","a","0"],
        ["You __ go home now","can","open","was","a","0"],
        ["She ___ her breakfast","ate","play","sleep","a","0"],
        ["Select the verb","John","is","table","b","0"],    
        ["We ___ planning to go to the movies tonight","were","could","can","b","0"],
        ["What ____ that noise?","Were","Was","Can","b","0"],
        ["What ___ your name?","are","can","is","c","0"]
        ];
        index = Random.Range(0,englishLecture.length);
        while(englishLecture[index][5] == "1")
         {
             index = Random.Range(0,englishLecture.length);
         }
        englishLecture[index][5] == "1";

        TextGUI =  GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Question");
        TextGUI.GetComponent(GUIText).text = englishLecture[index][0];
        sel1 = englishLecture[index][1];
        sel2 = englishLecture[index][2];
        sel3 = englishLecture[index][3];
        rightAns = englishLecture[index][4];
    }
    else if(MasterVar.quiz>=10)
    {
            Application.LoadLevel("Score");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should indent the code snippet, and have better title, and add tags for Unity and the language used...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow; it's not 100% clear what you're asking, remember we don't know your code base. In plain English, what, exactly, are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Or you could do it @hyde; you have the rep and the languages were in the question... and it's nice to be nice to the new person.

Comment: i'm trying to change the value form 0 to 1 if the arrays index is already been picked, while the value of [index][5] == 0 it will proceed but if it is equal to 1 it has to be randomize again to picked another index

Comment: @Ben yes, normally I would have edited, but I was writing that (and this) from a phone browser, which makes anything but straight text writing somewhat painful...

Comment: i just want to randomize it without repetition

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the "0"/"1" value is meant to store whether a question was asked previously or not, and that the while loop is meant to select a new random question until an unanswered one is found.

You are already changing the value from "0" to "1", but the main issue is that you're never reading it again once it's set to "1".

If you want your application to remember that a question was marked as answered ("1"), you'll need to write that data to a local file, and read the array from that file when the application starts. You'll need to learn about file I/O and serialization to do that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms172873.aspx

If you only need to ask another question after the first random question was asked, then you'll need to repeat the code that asks questions after the first question was marked as answered. You can do that by using a while loop, events, or encapsulating the question-asking code into a function. It's all about structure!

For instance, you'd want to go from this:

```
index = Random.Range(0,englishLecture.length); 

while(englishLecture[index][5] == "1") { 
    index = Random.Range(0,englishLecture.length); 
} 

englishLecture[index][5] == "1";

TextGUI =  GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Question");
TextGUI.GetComponent(GUIText).text = englishLecture[index][0];
sel1 = englishLecture[index][1];
sel2 = englishLecture[index][2];
sel3 = englishLecture[index][3];
rightAns = englishLecture[index][4];

//Add code to manage user interaction here
```

... to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  // This will ask 5 questions
    AskRandomQuestion();
}

function AskRandomQuestion() {

    index = Random.Range(0,englishLecture.length); 

    while(englishLecture[index][5] == "1") { 
        index = Random.Range(0,englishLecture.length); 
    } 

    englishLecture[index][5] == "1";

    TextGUI =  GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Question");
    TextGUI.GetComponent(GUIText).text = englishLecture[index][0];
    sel1 = englishLecture[index][1];
    sel2 = englishLecture[index][2];
    sel3 = englishLecture[index][3];
    rightAns = englishLecture[index][4];

    //Add code to manage user interaction here
}
```

Also, note that when all questions will be marked as answered, the while clause will loop infinitely, never finding an unanswered question, and the application will crash.

A better design would be to extract all unanswered questions into a new array (creating an array that only contains unanswered questions). If that array isn't empty, you can just pick a random question in it. Otherwise, you know all questions were already answered.

Something like that:

```
function AskRandomQuestion() {

    unasweredQuestions = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < englishLecture.length; i++) {
        if (englishLecture[i][5] == "0") {
            unansweredQuestions.push(englishLecture[i]);
        }
    }

    if (unansweredQuestions.length > 0) {
        selectedQuestion = unansweredQuestions[Random.Range(0,unansweredQuestions.length)]
        selectedQuestion[5] == "1";

        TextGUI =  GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Question");
        TextGUI.GetComponent(GUIText).text = selectedQuestion[0];
        sel1 = selectedQuestion[1];
        sel2 = selectedQuestion[2];
        sel3 = selectedQuestion[3];
        rightAns = selectedQuestion[4];

        // Add code to manage user interaction here
    } else {
        // All questions were answered, quit or reset
    }

}
```

This is all untested code that would benefit from some optimization, but it should help you get started.